# Google Cardboard simple App

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have created 3d models of some objects and see them correctly using cardboard through sketchfab.com without any difficulty.
I can see them as a VR model exactly what I wanted.
But I dont know how to create a standalone android app using my 3d model.
I am just looking for a template mobile application where I will place my model and see them as a mobile app through cardboard.
Any recommendation for an early start?

Answer (score 1):

After lots of research, I found out the best solution is using Unity3D application. There are plugins to assist with cardboard app development. I created my first app very easily within minutes of using a demo carboard application. Now I am enjoying and learning Unity3D

Answer (score 0):

The cardboard example? Might be a bit of hacking to chop out their block model and replace it with your art but it shouldn't be a mountain of work

https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java